# Calling a method after set amount of time and/or aborting thread issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, thread-abort

So I've got an application that employs a filesystemWatcher and triggers an event just fine. The FSW will trigger a bunch of times pretty close together. I want to create a function that triggers say an hour after the last time the FSW was triggered.

I first tried using a backgroundworker: (All code is shortened for clarity)

```
namespace Devo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        private void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (bw.IsBusy)
            {
                bw.CancelAsync(); //this is to, in a way, reset the timer for the delayed method.
            }

            //do a lot of stuff

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            while(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 180000)
            {
                if (bw.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    sw.Stop();
                    sw.Reset();
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();
            sw.Reset();

            DelayedMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work as the second time `bw.RunWorkerAsync()` was called it was apparently busy, even though the call to `bw.CancelAsync()`.

My next attempt involved a regular thread as I read somewhere on SO (can't find the link now) that one could not "restart" a backgroundWorker as I am trying to do.

The thread attemp is nearly identical but I thought I'd try in since there might be some constraints within the backgroundWorker that is not present in a regular thread. I thought.

```
namespace Devo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread PWC_counter_thread = new Thread(PWC_Counter);

        private void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (PWC_counter_thread.IsAlive)
                PWC_counter_thread.Abort();

            //do a lot of stuff

            PWC_counter_thread.Start();
        }

        static void PWC_Counter()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(180000);

            DelayedMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

But this gave me the same error. On the second call to `PWC_counter_thread.Start()` is was busy.

I'm assuming that a race condition is **not** present as the second thread waits for, in this example, 3 minutes, and the initial FSW method takes a good full second to execute, therefore I believe that the call to .Abort() and .CancelAsync() both are done before their respective methods are completed.

Now for the questions:

Is it possible to restart a thread in the fashion I am trying? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Should I delay my method call in another way? If so, tips?

**EDIT/UPDATE/SOLUTION**

I never got starting and stopping a thread to work as I wanted so I found another solution to my situation.

The situation was that I had a second thread that worked as a sort of timer where it would call a method after a set amount of time. My first thread did some work and upon finishing it would start the second thread. If the first thread got fired up again before the timer-thread had finished it was supposed to kill the thread and restart it.
This proved, for me, to be difficult to get the way I wanted. So I instead took another approach towards my wanted end result. Instead of restarting the thread I simply restarted the stopwatch that my second thread was using as a counter. This gave me the result I wanted. It's probably bad practice but it works.

Comment: Just a thought, but you could use a (threadsafe) queue that is filled by the fsw and a seperate timer that always empties the queue, including items that are added while working. It could be a fixed timer, or one that is fired by a helper method when the queue is filled (if not already running)  (of course, this suggestion is only of use when the fsw actually adds logic and is not only a starting point)

Answer (score 1):

In your `BackgroundWorker` example you probably have an issue with racing. `CancelAsync()`, as its name implies, is an asynchronious call, meaning that `BackgroundWorker` does not stop working immediately and it might still work when try to restart it. To avoid that, you should subscribe to `RunWorkerCompleted` event and wait for it to fire before calling `bw.RunWorkerAsync();` again. For example:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += OnCompleted;
    }

    private BackgroundWorker bw;
    private ManualResetEvent completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void OnCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        completed.Set();
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (bw.IsBusy)
        {
            bw.CancelAsync();
            completed.WaitOne();
        }

        //do a lot of stuff

        completed.Reset();
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

You have multiple issues with your `Thread`-based example.

1. You should never call `Thread.Abort()`. Instead, you should implement a cancellation mechanism, similar to that of BackgroundWorker. Make a `bool` field (`_isCancelled` or something) and check it periodically in thread delegate.
2. You can not reuse a `Thread` object. You should always create a new one.

Comment: Could you provide an example of subscribing to RunWorkerCompleted? I don't think I've done that before. But I'm self taught so maybe it's just the terminology I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: I get this - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.ManualResetEvent' to 'System.Threading.AutoResetEvent'

Comment: @ChristopherSirén, fixed typo

Comment: it appears that the code get's stuck at `completed.WaitOne();` and it freezes the program. I've got the completed.Set(); in my RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: @ChristopherSirén, it means that your `backgroundWorker_DoWork` method is never completed. You should debug it (even if your application freezes, you can still pause it from visual studio and see whats going on in `backgroundWorker_DoWork` method, sinse it is executed on separate thread).

Comment: A note on the issue: my RunWorkerCompleted is not entered when the BGW is cancelled. What could cause this?

Comment: @ChristopherSirén, see my comment above.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting closer to a solution of sorts, or anyhow the cause of my problem. It seems that RunWorkerCompleted is only fired after a successful iteration of DoWork. When the BGW is cancelled RunWorkerCompleted is **not** called and therefore completed.Set() is not called when the operation is cancelled, this leaves completed.WaitOne() running infinitely. I've used BGW before and cancelled it successfully in another project, I'm going through that now but kind find any dissimilarities that warrant this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @ChristopherSirén, check the documentation for this event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . It says, that it is raised when `DoWork` returns. It _doen not matter_ if it was cancelled or not. So clearly you should look for error in your `backgroundWorker_DoWork` because it _does not return_ when cancellation is requested.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best off encapsulating this in a class, and use a System.Threading.Timer to detect the inactivity.

Here's an example I put together. The idea is that you create an `InactivityDetector` with the appropriate inactivity threshold (an hour in your case) and a callback method that will be called when that period of inactivity is exceeded.

You have to call `InactivityDetector.RegisterActivity()` whenever activity is detected (e.g. in your case a file creation is detected).

Once the inactivity callback has been issued, it will not be called again until `RegisterActivity()` has been called again (this prevents multiple callbacks for the same period of extended inactivity).

Your code would pass `DelayedMethod` for the inactivity Action delegate.

Note that the callback is on a separate thread!

(Also note that I didn't put in any parameter validation, to keep the code shorter.)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    sealed class Program
    {
        void test()
        {
            using (var inactivityDetector = new InactivityDetector(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), inactivityDetected))
            {
                for (int loop = 0; loop < 3; ++loop)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Keeping busy once a second for 5 seconds.");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Registering activity");
                        inactivityDetector.RegisterActivity();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Entering 3 second inactivity");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    inactivityDetector.RegisterActivity();
                }
            }
        }

        static void inactivityDetected()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inactivity detected.");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().test();
        }
    }

    public sealed class InactivityDetector: IDisposable
    {
        public InactivityDetector(TimeSpan inactivityThreshold, Action onInactivity)
        {
            _inactivityThreshold = inactivityThreshold;
            _onInactivity        = onInactivity;
            _timer               = new Timer(timerCallback, null, (int)inactivityThreshold.TotalMilliseconds, -1);
        }

        public void RegisterActivity()
        {
            _timer.Change(-1, -1);
            _timer.Change((int)_inactivityThreshold.TotalMilliseconds, -1);
        }

        private void timerCallback(object state)
        {
            _timer.Change(-1, -1);
            _onInactivity();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }

        private readonly TimeSpan _inactivityThreshold;
        private readonly Action _onInactivity;
        private readonly Timer _timer;
    }
}
```